# Sorting summary stat values in ggplot2

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

The following code summarises the mean values by group, which is great. However, I would like to be able to sort those values. Any idea how to add to the code that the mean values should be sorted?

Data:

```
df=data.frame(score=c(4,2,3,5,7,6,5,6,4,2,3,5,4,8),
              age=c(18,18,23,50,19,39,19,23,22,22,40,35,22,16))

# Option 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(age), y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")

# Option 2
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(age), y = score)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_reorder` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = forcats::fct_reorder(factor(age), score, mean), y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") + 
  xlab('age')
```

[image]